# "The most frequently available devices are walking canes and talking watch."

Tags: sentence-construction, superlatives

> The most frequently available devices are walking canes and talking watch.

In the sentence, Is it correct If I mention two devices even though I use "the most frequent"?

OR I should mention only one device. In the same way, lest frequently available devices color detector, electronic cane, liquid sensor.

Comment: Your sentence is fine - although it requires **watches** in the plural.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of answers to this question:

If the canes and the watches are available and/or used in roughly equal quantities, then suraj is correct in that "watch" needs to be plural.

If using multiple canes with a single watch, or multiple canes but only one watch is available, then you'd need to restructure the sentence:

> A talking watch and walking canes are the more frequently available devices.

In this way, you can reference a single item and a group of items at the same time.